# Entering paths in PHP

Tags: php

I know this seems something very elementary but its driving me nuts.

I have 3 folders in my domain which are:

1. admin
2. source
3. destination

All three folders are on the same level.

In the admin folder I have a PHP file called xyz.php

This PHP basically transfers files from the 'source' to the 'destination' folder. The script works fine. But when I put the xyz.php in admin it ceased to stop. Basically because xyz.php uses paths of 'source' and 'destination'. Since I transferred it to admin I cannot manage to find the correct paths of the folders.

Comment: Could you share the code which references these paths?

Comment: `$ImagesDirectory    = '/../source/'; //Source Image Directory End with Slash
$DestImagesDirectory    = '/../destination/'; //Destination Image Directory End with Slash`

Comment: @MtDemonics Please edit your question instead of appending comments…

Comment: Have you tried removing the leading / as that looks at the root then goes up one level, rather than a relational path?

Comment: "In the admin folder I have a PHP file called xyz.php" and "when I put the xyz.php in admin" are contradict themselves.

Comment: @feeela because before I transfered the file I tested the script. Then I transfered the xyz.php into the admin folder.

Comment: Ok found the solution seems to have worked Strangely enough it seems to have worked now:

`
$ImagesDirectory    = '../source/'; 
$DestImagesDirectory    = '../destination/'; 
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should work:

> $ImagesDirectory = '../source/';
>
> $DestImagesDirectory = '../destination/';

Just remove the slash in front...

Comment: have you tried to use an absolute path? Or can you post a snippet how you handle the files?

Comment: No I havent because I don't know how to.

Comment: (depending on your operating system) something like ´/home/mtdemonics/dev/php/source/´ or ´C:/users/mtdemonics/dev/php/source/´

Comment: Strangely enough it seems to have worked now:

`$ImagesDirectory    = '../source/'; 
$DestImagesDirectory    = '../destination/'; `